# Tidyverse version of base R code for plogis?

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, tidyverse

**The problem**

I am converting some R code that uses base R into code that uses the tidyverse and I'm getting a bit stuck. Here's a relevant snippet of the code that I'm trying to convert:

```
J <- c(2, 3, 7, 3, 50) # male or not, eth, age, income level, state
  poststrat <- as.data.frame(array(NA, c(prod(J), length(J)+1))) # Columns of post-strat matrix, plus one for size
  colnames(poststrat) <- c("male", "eth", "age","income", "state",'N')
  count <- 0
  for (i1 in 1:J[1]){
    for (i2 in 1:J[2]){
      for (i3 in 1:J[3]){
        for (i4 in 1:J[4]){
          for (i5 in 1:J[5]){
            count <- count + 1
            # Fill them in so we know what category we are referring to
            poststrat[count, 1:5] <- c(i1-1, i2, i3,i4,i5) 
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  
  coef_male <- c(0,-0.3)
  coef_eth <- c(0, 0.6, 0.9)
  coef_age <- c(0,-0.2,-0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.7, 0.8)
  coef_income <- c(0,-0.2, 0.6)
  coef_state <- c(0, round(rnorm(49, 0, 1), 1))
  coef_age_male <- t(cbind(c(0, .1, .23, .3, .43, .5, .6),
                           c(0, -.1, -.23, -.5, -.43, -.5, -.6)))
  true_popn <- data.frame(poststrat[, 1:5], cat_pref = rep(NA, prod(J)))
  for (j in 1:prod(J)) {
    true_popn$cat_pref[j] <- plogis(
      coef_male[poststrat[j, 1] + 1] +
        coef_eth[poststrat[j, 2]] + coef_age[poststrat[j, 3]] +
        coef_income[poststrat[j, 4]] + coef_state[poststrat[j, 5]] +
        coef_age_male[poststrat[j, 1] + 1, poststrat[j, 3]]
    )
  }
```

This is specifically the part of the code that I'm struggling with:

```
  true_popn <- data.frame(poststrat[, 1:5], cat_pref = rep(NA, prod(J)))
  for (j in 1:prod(J)) {
    true_popn$cat_pref[j] <- plogis(
      coef_male[poststrat[j, 1] + 1] +
        coef_eth[poststrat[j, 2]] + coef_age[poststrat[j, 3]] +
        coef_income[poststrat[j, 4]] + coef_state[poststrat[j, 5]] +
        coef_age_male[poststrat[j, 1] + 1, poststrat[j, 3]]
    )
  }
```

I know what this code does - it loops through all the assigned coefficients and converts a log odds into a probability via the `plogis` function. What I'm unclear about is how I can do this using the tidyverse.

**Here's what I've tried**

My gut instinct was to use the `expand_grid` function and to then apply the `plogis` function to the row sums:

```
  coef_male <- c(0,-0.3)
  coef_eth <- c(0, 0.6, 0.9)
  coef_age <- c(0,-0.2,-0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.7, 0.8)
  coef_income <- c(0,-0.2, 0.6)
  coef_state <- c(0, round(rnorm(49, 0, 1), 1))
  coef_age_male <- t(cbind(c(0, .1, .23, .3, .43, .5, .6),
                           c(0, -.1, -.23, -.5, -.43, -.5, -.6)))
  expand_grid(coef_male,
              coef_eth,
              coef_age,
              coef_income,
              coef_state)
```

This code works because I can get the 6,300 cells that I'm wanting, but it is not able to incorporate the `coef_age_male` variable that I want. Using expand grid with this variable makes a grid that's bigger than the 6,300 that I need.

**My question**

Can somebody help me replace the loop using the `plogis` function to something with dplyr? I'm thinking that it will be easier to understand and more readable by colleagues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a `data.frame` of coefficients not containing the original codes (e.g. `male`: `0`, `1`). The ordering is different, but we can bring it in a different order, if necessary, with `arrange`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

coef_male <- c(0,-0.3)
coef_eth <- c(0, 0.6, 0.9)
coef_age <- c(0,-0.2,-0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.7, 0.8)
coef_income <- c(0,-0.2, 0.6)
coef_state <- c(0, round(rnorm(49, 0, 1), 1))
coef_age_male <- t(cbind(c(0, .1, .23, .3, .43, .5, .6),
                         c(0, -.1, -.23, -.5, -.43, -.5, -.6)))
# lets turn the matrix above into a vector
coef_age_male2 = c(0, .1, .23, .3, .43, .5, .6, 
                   0, -.1, -.23, -.5, -.43, -.5, -.6) 
# now we can create a look-up data.frame
look_up <- crossing(male = coef_male,
                    age = coef_age) %>% 
  arrange(desc(male)) %>% 
  mutate(age_male = coef_age_male2)

# create a matrix of coefficients and join together
cross_df(list(
         male = coef_male, 
         eth = coef_eth,
         age = coef_age,
         income = coef_income,
         state = coef_state)) %>% 
  left_join(look_up, by = c("male", "age")) %>% 
  mutate(cat_pref = select(.,male:age_male) %>% 
                      rowSums() %>%
                      plogis()
         )
#> # A tibble: 6,300 x 7
#>     male   eth   age income state age_male cat_pref
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#>  1   0     0     0        0     0     0.23    0.557
#>  2  -0.3   0     0        0     0    -0.23    0.371
#>  3   0     0.6   0        0     0     0.23    0.696
#>  4  -0.3   0.6   0        0     0    -0.23    0.517
#>  5   0     0.9   0        0     0     0.23    0.756
#>  6  -0.3   0.9   0        0     0    -0.23    0.591
#>  7   0     0    -0.2      0     0     0.1     0.475
#>  8  -0.3   0    -0.2      0     0    -0.1     0.354
#>  9   0     0.6  -0.2      0     0     0.1     0.622
#> 10  -0.3   0.6  -0.2      0     0    -0.1     0.5  
#> # … with 6,290 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>